# can't add a class to the tab by clicking a button- js is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I can't active the tab by clicking the next button in tab2. I want that if i click on the "next" tab3 content will appear. as well as the tab3 will be active also.
I used another way to change the content and active the tab but then tab is not active then(for tab1).

html code:

```
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="hi">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>                            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1info">
            tab1 contents
            <a href="#tab2info " data-toggle="tab">Next</a>
        </div>                            
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2info">
            <a onclick="iyo()" id="aaa">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3info">tab3contents</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js code:

```
 function iyo () {
     $('tab3info').addClass('active');
 };
```

Comment: `$('tab3info')` selects an element that looks like `<tab3info></tab3info>`, probably not what you wanted, but `$('#tab3info')`, and that's a typo

Comment: I tried this also but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Your code is jQuery, not plain javascript. Are you actually loading the jQuery library? Where in your document do you define your function? Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: For reference, here is your code working when set up correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/4rsyLfr2/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this working code.

```js
 function iyo() {
        $('[href="#tab2info"]').parent().removeClass('active');
        $('#tab2info').removeClass('active in');
        $('[href="#tab3info"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('#tab3info').addClass('active in');
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="hi">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1info">
                tab1 contents
                      <a href="#tab2info " data-toggle="tab">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2info">
                <a onclick="iyo()" id="aaa">Next</a>
            </div>


            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3info">tab3contents</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```